# After converting Android project to Maven, I cannot run as android project

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I had an working Android project on Eclipse Mars and I wanted to add a Maven dependency. I followed some tutorials and successfully converted the project into a Maven project by using "Install New Software" for m2e, "Eclipse Marketplace" for android-m2e.

Now, I wanted to RUN the project, but all of a sudden, "run as Android Application" setting has been removed. When I tried to run as saved configuration (android application), it says "myprojectname is not an Android Project!".

I'm trying to make this work but for the whole day I'm stuck and can't figure it out :( I wish I committed the change right before I did this ..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself, but I'm leaving this thread to people who might encounter similar problem.

What I did

1. removed both m2e and android-m2e from eclipse.
2. removed the project from Project Explorer in eclipse (IMPORTANT: DO NOT SELECT "DELETE PROJECT CONTENTS ON DISK(CANNOT BE UNDONE)" UNLESS YOU MEANT TO DO IT)
3. File->New..->Other->Android->Android Project from Existing Code -> select your project

Now I have my project generating "gen" correctly.

Hope this solves someone's problem.